# why is SSE cost function convex?

Tags: machine-learning

In regards to Machine Learning, in the Adaline rule we say that

$$
J(w)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i} (\mbox{target}^{(i)} - \mbox{output}^{(i)})^2, \quad \mbox{output}^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}
$$

is convex. I´d like to know how can we say that? Some proof that it is always convex.

Thank you in advance

Comment: @VHarisop thank you for the edit

Answer (score 1):

Please check that the Hessian matrix is positively semidefinite.

For a more concrete answer please write precisely what do you understand by $w$.

Comment: w is the weight of each feature in the rule (an object can have several weights). It represents a value that will decide in a future experiment if a certain object belongs to a class or another class based on that feature.